# Align two divs one to left and one to immediate right of center

Tags: css

How do I align two divs such that one is to the extreme left and other is to the immediate right of center.
Note that its not in center. Its just sticked to center . Something like this

```
div                 |div
```

here | represents the center of the page

I tried giving width:50% but on page resize its not giving expected result and all divs are rearranging differently. I tried giving margin-left and right as well but same problem

```
<div class="help-bar-div">
    <hr>
    <div style="display:inline-block;">
        <div style="display:inline-block;margin-left:0;width:50%; margin-right:0">
           text1
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;float:right; margin-left:-11px;">
           text2
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. What is your HTML structure?

Comment: added what I have tried

Comment: Has the containing div got any width set? Or is the width of the page determined by the two inner divs? Ie what sets the page’s width?

Comment: Page width is default width. No, the width is not determined by two inner divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use display flex on the container and flex-grow to fill equal spaces

```html
<div style="display:flex;">
  <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
    text1
  </div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1;">
    text2
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more as I don’t understand the significance of the display settings.

Comment: this could be achieved by     <div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;width:50%;">
           text1
        </div>
        <div style="display:inline-block;">
           text2
        </div>
    </div>
since the question mentioned page resize I think display flex would be a better choice

Comment: Yes, your original answer kept the display settings in the two divs, it was those I wondered about. I see they have now gone.